# Add a WCF Service Reference from another project

Tags: wpf, wcf

I am working on a **WPF project in Visual Studio 2010**. I want to import a WCF service reference from another project to this project.

> *I tried to do it manually by copying and pasting it*, Visual Studio did not recognize it as a service reference. Instead *it got added
>   like just another folder*.

**Is there any other way to import a service reference?**

Comment: both projects are in same solution ?

Comment: you are not copy pest directly to another project

Comment: you can do one thing create class librery of wcf project and expose  that wcf service project and after that you can consume that wcf Service to another project

Comment: @HiddenBrain :Actually I am looking for a way to import the service reference from another WPF project. I dont want to run the WCF project and consume it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the WCF service on your local IIS, add the WCF reference in your project from localhost/yourWCF.
You can make in the config file an app setting key that points to the real WCF address, on app start, you can add a compile condition that overrides the localhost url with the real address if you'r running on release mode.